# Query with postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Here below some sample 3 data, using PostgreSQL and rails

```
Stock
id: 42324
name: 'n1'

    stock_items

     id: 57889359
     stock_id: 42324
     check_id: 14123
     turn: 5
     mock_id: 57889357

     id: 57889360
     stock_id: 42324
     check_id: 14141
     turn: 3
     mock_id: 0

Stock
id: 42325
name: 'n1'

    stock_items

     id: 57889361
     stock_id: 42325
     check_id: 19499
     turn: 5
     mock_id: 57889359

     id: 57889362
     stock_id: 42325
     check_id: 19500
     turn: 3
     mock_id: 0
```

Here i have stock table and stock_items table i am trying to take the result like
if mock_id is 0 then get the check_id else other check_id whose mock_id is not zero.

So i tried one query

```
SELECT 
    check_id1, 
    CASE 
        WHEN stock_items.mock_id = 0 THEN stock_items.check_id 
        ELSE stock_items.check_id  
    END as check_id2 
FROM
    stock_items 
    INNER JOIN stocks on stocks.id = stock_items.stock_id ;
```

but the above query fails, but i need it like below, any suggestions?

```
check_id1 (mock_id=0) | check_id2 (mock_id !=0)
----------------------+-----------------------
                14141 |    14123
                19500 |    19499
```

Answer (score 2):

CASE statement doesn't work like you think. You can read it here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html

Your query shoud look like this
`SELECT s.check_id1, s2.check_id1 FROM stock_items s, (SELECT * FROM stock_items WHERE mock_id <> 0) s2  WHERE s.stock_id = s2.stock_id`

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is basically a `PIVOT`. You should actually use *two* [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html), within an aggregation function, and having a `GROUP BY` (and an `ORDER BY` to get the order you gave):

```
SELECT 
    stock_id,
    max(CASE when mock_id =0 then check_id END) AS "check_id1 (mock_id=0)", 
    max(CASE when mock_id<>0 then check_id END) AS "check_id2 (mock_id!=0)"
FROM
    stock_items 
    INNER JOIN stocks on stocks.id = stock_items.stock_id 
GROUP BY
    stock_id 
ORDER BY
    stock_id;
```

```
stock_id | check_id1 (mock_id=0) | check_id2 (mock_id!=0)
-------: | --------------------: | ---------------------:
   42324 |                 14141 |                  14123
   42325 |                 19500 |                  19499
```

NOTE: I've added the `stock_id` so that the result is easier to understand. You can omit it if you don't actually want it in your response.

You can check all the setup and test it at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ad5fe092ad9037bbc8ecd8dbf2d54c51)*

---

**UPDATE**

As per comments

```
SELECT
    stock_id,
    -- This will get rid of the null in array_agg
    ARRAY(SELECT 
        e
     FROM 
         unnest(all_check_ids_with_mock_id_0) AS e
     WHERE 
         e IS NOT NULL
    ) AS all_check_ids_with_mock_id_0,
    ARRAY(SELECT
        e
    FROM 
        unnest(all_check_ids_with_mock_id_non_0) AS e
    WHERE 
        e IS NOT NULL
    ) AS all_check_ids_with_mock_id_non_0
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        stock_id, 
        array_agg(CASE WHEN mock_id =0 THEN check_id END) AS all_check_ids_with_mock_id_0,
        array_agg(CASE WHEN mock_id<>0 THEN check_id END) AS all_check_ids_with_mock_id_non_0
    FROM
        stock_items 
        INNER JOIN stocks on stocks.id = stock_items.stock_id 
    GROUP BY
        stock_id
    ) AS q0
ORDER BY
    stock_id;
```

```
stock_id | all_check_ids_with_mock_id_0 | all_check_ids_with_mock_id_non_0
-------: | :--------------------------- | :-------------------------------
20223028 | {48752}                      | {194907,19260}                  
20223029 | {48743}                      | {194945,194907}                 
20223030 | {48752}                      | {194907}                        
20223031 | {48752}                      | {194907}
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a20d87f3197ba591dd317f2abaf017d2)*

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i had tried that with case, here  i have updated that fiddle http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=fb87680ea8ce6397f5b2e126fcf08a70, i need one more clarificaiton here i can't user max becausue i need all the data also is there any way to avoid the duplicate of check_id1 and check_id2?

Comment: In your dbfiddle: If your pivot column is `mock_id`, you shouldn't `GROUP BY` it. If you want all your data, you can use `array_agg` instead of `max`. you'll get an *array* of values if there is more than one. If you want to *unpack that info again*, you can use later unnest. I don't fully get it, because I don't see any array with more than one element: *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=3f9c27f3442afd85fbdb1842c7b9833e)*

Comment: thanks, I mean in this http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=3f9c27f3442afd85fbdb1842c7b9833e that order ids (20223030, 20223031) where the check_id1 and check_id2 is repeating so is there any way to avoid that.

Comment: I still don't get it. My answer gave the result you asked for in your question. I think you should rephrase your question and put an example of what you *really* want. I think you just *don't want to `group by stock_items.check_id`...  My latest ***speculation*** *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6e4e161fe550fb66fe90bfd03137d8f6)*

Comment: Yes, now i can tell you, in this http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6e4e161fe550fbl66fe90bfd03137d8f6 , showing the fields all_check_ids  CASE 1: for example {194945,48743,194907}, here the 48743 is mock_id 0 value, and other two value are mock_id non zero, i need it like one column have 48743 and other column have 194945, 194907. CASE 2: for example {194907,48752} here this combination is repeating in that fiddle i want to avoid that repetition also. it will be helpful if you can open a chat.

Comment: Check *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a20d87f3197ba591dd317f2abaf017d2)* (which does NOT produce the answer you asked for, but I think it is what you're looking for)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149288/discussion-between-django-and-joanolo).

Comment: thanks, this is the one i am looking for,
is there any way to avoid the duplication?
i meant the last two rows have same, so is there any way to avoid any of that stock ids 20223030 or 20223031